# Angular Typescript Error: Property 'hobbies' does not exist on type '{ name: string; occupation: string; age: number; hobbies: string; }[]'

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object

First Stack Overflow Post.

New to Angular and Typescript.

I'm working on an exercise where I'm trying to display an array of objects. I followed these tutorials and feel like my code should be working based on what I have typed up and what the tutorial shows:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjq6Wwgkka8
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=53ftOZ-Q4N4&list=PL8p2I9GklV47eNpoo4Fr6fkags72a8F0v&index=20

The only difference is I added the code based on my instructors instructions: `implements OnInit`. And: `ngOnInit(): void{ }`.

The errors I'm getting are:

```
Error: src/app/app.component.html:6:15 - error TS2339: Property 'hobbies' does not exist on type '{ name: string; occupation: string; age: number; hobbies: string; }[]'.

6   <li>{{users.hobbies}}</li>
                ~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:6:16
    6   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CardFancyExample.
```

This error is happening for every key : value pair in my array.

See code below:

HTML:

```
<h1>{{users.name}}</h1>

<ul *ngFor="let item of users">
  <li>{{users.occupation}}</li>
  <li>{{users.age}}</li>
  <li>{{users.hobbies}}</li>
</ul>
```

Typescript:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class CardFancyExample implements OnInit { //always make sure to have the "implements OnInit" after the object name
  //create an array of people
  users=[
    {
      name: "Albus Dumbledore",
      occupation: "Headmaster of Hogwarts",
      age: 112,
      hobbies: "Knitting"
    },
    {
      name: "Harry Potter",
      occupation: "Student at Hogwarts",
      age: 16,
      hobbies: "Quidditch"
    },
    {
      name: "Arthur Weasley",
      occupation: "MOM : Misuse of Muggle Artifacts Office",
      age: 55,
      hobbies: "Collector"
    },
  ]
 
  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }
}
```

Based on my research of this error it seems it might be a typescript issue:
[https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-property-does-not-exist-on-type-object#:~:text=The%20%22Property%20does%20not%20exist,type%20with%20variable%20key%20names](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-property-does-not-exist-on-type-object#:%7E:text=The%20%22Property%20does%20not%20exist,type%20with%20variable%20key%20names).

But I'm wanting to confirm as I don't have a lot of experience with Angular or Typescript. So I'm not sure if this is the right solution for my particular error.

Comment: users is an array and does not have any fields, you should access those fields using the item variable you've declared in the for loop. item.hobbies , item.name etc.

Answer (score 0):

What Berk said, you have a typo, `user` instead of `item`, this will work:

```html
<ul *ngFor="let item of users">
  <li>{{item.occupation}}</li>
  <li>{{item.age}}</li>
  <li>{{item.hobbies}}</li>
</ul>
```